# Selector :not with operators in SCSS

Tags: sass, node-sass

I have a problem with node-sass 7.0.1.
When use a pseudo class :not sass not compile and not show any error.

This is my code:

```
.wf-field--inline {
    & > *:not(label + *) {
        border-top-left-radius: 0 !important;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
.wf-field--inline > * ;
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you still using `node-sass` ??

Comment: I using node-sass for compiling scss with npm. At that time, I think it was the best option. Dart-sass is a solution?

Comment: See the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can start with just `sass` because `node-sass` is old news now.

**Steps**

`npm install --save-dev sass` or `yarn add -D sass`

And then in your `package.json` under `scripts`

```json
"scripts": {
  "compile": "sass main.scss -w --no-source-map -q main.css"
}
```

Learn more about flags [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass)

Comment: Wow thanks, tomorrow try change my config in package.json and replace all. When I test this change I respond.